# Javascript regex: why groups with one syntax, and not the other

Tags: javascript, regex

I just spent a couple of hours wondering why a regular expression that I thought I understood, wasn't giving me the results I expected.

Consider these two ways of using the same regular expression:

```
var str="This will put us on the map!"
var a=str.match(/(?:\bwill\W+)(\w+)(\W+)/g)
alert(a[0]) //will put
alert(a[1]) //undefined

var regex=/(?:\bwill\W+)(\w+)(\W+)/g
var match = regex.exec(str)
alert(match[0]) //will put
alert(match[1]) //put
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tn2Da/15/)

Obviously, the latter form is working properly; but what's wrong with the former?

Also, for thoroughness:

```
var re = new RegExp("(?:\\bwill\\W+)(\\w+)(\\W+)","g")
var rematch = re.exec(str)
alert(rematch[0]) //will put
alert(rematch[1]) //put
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tn2Da/16/)

When I was searching here, I came across [this question ("Javascript Regex Missing Groups")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15190619/javascript-regex-missing-groups) which claims that the g flag was causing the problem.  However, that is clearly not the problem here, since the RE is exactly the same in the two cases, the only difference is how it's executed.

Thanks for your help!

Edit: The responses below do an excellent job of clearing this up. One thing I learned from this that I'd like to make clear for the record, is that the re.exec() method can be used to get all the matches, and it can also be used to get all the groups, but the way of accessing those two modes is somewhat subtle: With or without the g flag, the return value is always an array with the full match followed by the match groups. It is never an array containing multiple matches. The way to access multiple matches is to call the exec() method again on the same RegExp object.

It was mystifying to me why I was unable to answer this question myself with several hours of Google searching. The behavior in question is described in the documentation of string.match() and RegExp.exec(), although it was not described in a way that made those come up with any of the search strings related to the way I was experiencing the problem.  So, for reference, I'm linking those here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Answer (score 2):

The difference is indeed with the `g` modifier. When used together with `.match()` it will yield all values of `$0` for each match that was found.

For example:

```
> "This will put us on the map!".match(/(\w+)/g)
["This", "will", "put", "us", "on", "the", "map"]
```

But:

```
> "This will put us on the map!".match(/(\w+)/)
["This", "This"]
```

Comment: It's still early morning here, so maybe that's why I don't see it: Why `["This", "This"]` in the 2nd example?

Comment: @UweB, as I have explained in my answer, the first "This" is matched one and the second "This" is the grouped one

Comment: @UweB, if you remove the group expression `( )`, then you'll get only one "This";

Comment: @UweB Yeah, the first element is `$0`, the second is `$1` of the match :)

Comment: I understood the behavior of str.match() ok, but what was throwing me off was that when used with the exec() method, the g flag also yields all the different matches, you just have to get at them by calling the method repeatedly. str.match() will NEVER give you the groups, though, it will only give you $0.

Answer (score 1):

`string.match` will only **match** the string and leaves of all sub expressions. It only matches `$0`.

It is meant only for matching. But if your match is inside a group, then you'll get duplicates. 1 will be the matched one and the other one will be the group.

Whereas, `regex.exec` with `g` modifier is used to be used in loops and the groups will be retained in the array.

### To put it simply:

`.match()` will only match the matched part of string without groups, an exception being is when the match itself is a group.

`.exec` will give you the match, the groups.

So use `.match` only when you want to find the match and use `.exec` when you want the groups.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some perspective to clarify the point the others have made:

```
var str="This will put us on the map will do this!"
var a=str.match(/(?:\bwill\W+)(\w+)(\W+)/g)
console.log(a);
```

gives you this:

`["will put ", "will do "]`

So when you have the `g` modifier, it only does a global match for the full pattern which would normally be `$0`.

It's not like e.g. php that gives you a multi-dim array of full pattern matches and grouped matches e.g.

```
preg_match_all('~(?:\bwill\W+)(\w+)(\W+)~',$string,$matches);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => will put 
            [1] => will do 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => put
            [1] => do
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  
            [1] =>  
        )

)
```

In javascript, you only ever get a single-dim array. So `.match` will either give you each element as the match the *full* pattern does (with `g` modifier), or else just element 0 as the full pattern match, and elements 1+ as the grouped.  Whereas `.exec` will *only* do the latter. Neither one of them will give you a multi-dim with both, like in my php example.