# Unexpected behavior of global-RegExp `Array.prototype.match()`

Tags: javascript, regex, match

The task is to find, whether there are, any series of ones (i.e. `"111"`) and output for each match:

1. Position of match in input;
2. Number of successive ones (i.e. for `"111"` it will be `2`);

---

I use following regexps: `/1(1+)/g` and `/1(1+)/`; unfortunately, none of them work properly:

```
var m = "11110110".match(/1(1+)/); // ["1111", "111"]
// `m[0]` is the first match and `m[1]` is a capture group of the first match;
// error: there is no second match

var mg = "11110110".match(/1(1+)/g); // ["1111", "11"]
// `mg[0]` is the first match and `mg[1]` is the second match;
// error: there are no capture groups
```

In the case of `"11110110"` input I need something like:

```
var mg = "11110110".__(/1(1+)/g); // [["1111", "111"], ["11", "1"]]
// `mg[0][0]` is the 1st match, `mg[0][1]` is its capture group,
// `mg[1][0]` is the 2nd match and `mg[1][1]` is its capture group;
```

Then for each match I define:

1. `position` as `input.indexOf(mg[i][0])`;
2. `number of successive digits` as `mg[i][1].length`;

---

How should I do that? What regexp or method should I use?
Or, maybe, there is a totally different technique, which I'm not familiar with?

---

P.S.: If I got it right, the question is not duplicate for [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22777792/javascript-regex-why-groups-with-one-syntax-and-not-the-other), since it is about *"how to"*, not *"why"*.

Comment: There is no such function in JS. You will need to loop until it yields `null`.

Comment: Do you need something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/jnjLdsgg/)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Sort of. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `exec` method of the String. `exec` returns an object with an index property:

```js
var str = '111001111';
var re = /(1+)/g;
while ((match = re.exec(str)) != null) {
    console.log(match[0]); // capture group
    console.log(match[0].length); // length
    console.log(match.index); // start index position
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `RegExp#exec()` to keep all captured texts in a match data object.

Here is a sample demo getting:

- all matches (just the 0th element in the match data object, `m[0]`)
- all indices (last re index minus the match length, `re.lastIndex - m[0].length`)
- length of the successive digits (the length of the first capture group value, `m[1].length`)

You may revamp it later as per your needs.

```js
var s = "11110110"; 
var re = /1(1+)/g;
var pos = [], numOfSucDigits = [], matches = [];
while ((m=re.exec(s)) !== null) {
  matches.push(m[0]);
  numOfSucDigits.push(m[1].length);
  pos.push(re.lastIndex - m[0].length);
}
document.body.innerHTML = "Matches: " + JSON.stringify(matches) + "<br/>";
document.body.innerHTML += "Count of SD: " + JSON.stringify(numOfSucDigits) + "<br/>";
document.body.innerHTML += "Indices: " + JSON.stringify(pos);
```